# django-admin file upload return 404 page in shared hosting (namecheap)

Tags: python, django, apache, shared-hosting, namecheap

I have deployed a Django app in namecheap shared hosting. All the page and functions are working fine except file upload. File upload from django-admin(return 404 page) and custom file upload form (render root page view) is not working. I have tried with flask app and file upload is working fine. All settings about media is ok.

I have contacted with namecheap support. But, they want specific problem which i can't find out.
I got similar  type  question in stackoverflow and other forum but nobody has replied.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I want to answer of my above question.
The issue was about Mod_Security. Need to disable it. I have figured out by talking with namecheap customer care and it's working fine.